# URL Rewriting .NET 4 not working?

Tags: .net-4.0, url-rewriting

I have been trying the most basic examples of URL rewriting in .net 4 and can nothing to work locally or on an IIS server?

This is my global.asax file

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" %>

<script runat="server">

void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // Code that runs on application startup
    RegisterRoutes(System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes); 

}

public static void RegisterRoutes(System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection routeCollection)
{
    routeCollection.MapPageRoute("RouteForCustomer", "Customer/{Id}", "~/Customer.aspx");
} 

void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    //  Code that runs on application shutdown

}

void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs

}

void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // Code that runs when a new session is started

}

void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // Code that runs when a session ends. 
    // Note: The Session_End event is raised only when the sessionstate mode
    // is set to InProc in the Web.config file. If session mode is set to StateServer 
    // or SQLServer, the event is not raised.

}

</script>
```

But when i call

```
http://localhost:3564/Customer/1
```

i just get HTTP not found?

Comment: What's the whitespace in your `"Customer/  {id}"`?

Comment: Sorry not wure why it shows like that there are no spaces in the code...I have updated it so it shows the correct code from my global.asax file now.