# How can I get a custom error page to display and rewrite the URL to something friendly?

Tags: .net, iis-7, url-rewriting, web-config, custom-error-pages

I've been pounding my head against the wall with what I see as a very simple task.

Quick background:

1. I am using URL Rewrite with IIS7
2. I am using a Rewrite Map to map `/ErrorPage.aspx` to `/Error` (among many others).
3. I have the `<customErrors>` config element set to "On" (to test locally) and the `defaultRedirect` set to "~/ErrorPage.aspx".
4. Framework 3.5

My issue is two-fold:

1. The rewrite to `/Error` is not working, even though every other rewrite on the site is working.
2. When an exception occurs, the URL shows `/ErrorPage.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/Blah`.

I'm not concerned about the errorpath because I'm catching the detailed exception message(s) sufficiently.

I read in [Another Overflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12955642/url-rewriting-net-4-not-working) that adding a query string to the `defaultRedirect` would get rid of the aspxerrorpath (which it did), but the actual rewrite is still not occurring.

Is there not a way to simply rewrite or redirect to `/Error` and actually display my error page?

I tried creating a rewrite rule to get rid of the aspxerrorpath, but it never succeeds.

```
<rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL3" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^([^/]+)/?$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="ErrorPage.aspx?aspxerrorpath={R:1}" />
</rule>
```

And then I attempted a separate one when appending the query string to the `defaultRedirect`:

```
<rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL3" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="ErrorPage.aspx?{R:1}={R:2}" />
</rule>
```

But, alas, neither is working.

I was, however, able to implement a 404 rewrite for my `PageNotFound.aspx` using the `<httpErrors>` config element, alongside my Rewrite Map.  It correctly rewrites to `/PageNotFound`.   **Is there a way to do this for the ErrorPage for all exceptions?**

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
    <clear />
    <error statusCode="404" responseMode="Redirect" path="PageNotFound" />
</httpErrors>
```

I feel like I must be missing something very simply and basic.